Error: PKCS#12 uses unsupported MAC algorithm: 1.2.804.2.1.1.1.1.2.1
Unable to sign pdf file with .pfx certificate due to error. Error: PKCS#12 is using an unsupported MAC algorithm: 1.2.804.2.1.1.1.1.2.1, this certificate is from Diia service, they also provided me with a .dat file, but I don't know what to do with it.
I am using Node.js:
  const assetAccessCode = await this.configFacade.get(SIGN_CERTIFICATE_ASSET_ACCESS_CODE);
  const assetId = await this.configFacade.get(SIGN_CERTIFICATE_ASSET_ID);

  let signer = await send(this.secureStorage, 'assetGet', { assetAccessCode, assetId, clientId }).catch((error) => {
    this.logger.error(`Secure Storage request:${JSON.stringify({ assetAccessCode, assetId, clientId })}`);
    this.logger.error(`Secure Storage unavailable:${JSON.stringify(error)}`);
    throw Error(error);
  });

 
  const pdfToSign = plainAddPlaceholder({
    pdfBuffer,
    reason: ' ',
    contactInfo: ' ',
    name: ' ',
    location: 'UK',
  });
  signer = new P12Signer(Buffer.from(signer.asset.certFile), {
    passphrase: signer.asset.password,
    asn1StrictParsing: true,
  });
  const signed = await signpdf.sign(pdfToSign, signer);
  return signed;

How can i recolve this issue

The deal is that Ukraine has its own cryptographic algorithms for digital signatures, which are not supported by any foreign libraries. The solution was to build an addon using UAPKI
